# iPhone ad hoc app icon replaced by placeholder icon during install

Tags: ios, iphone, icons

I'm using Apple's "over the air" (OTA) ad hoc distribution for a Hello World iPhone app. The app installs and runs as expected on my iPhone XR running iOS 16.4.1 except for one glitch. The app icon I furnished is displayed when the install begins, but after a couple of seconds it's replaced with the placeholder icon. When the install is done, only the placeholder icon is displayed.

I've seen references to iOS aborting loading of the icon .png file if it's too big or the server is too slow, but the entire icon is visible when the install begins, so the download seems to have finished.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

I tried various image sizes but the problem persists.

Here's the manifest.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://rhdev1.com/devX/MacInCloud/AdHocHelloWorld.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://rhdev1.com/devX/MacInCloud/image.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://rhdev1.com/devX/MacInCloud/image.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.marksteinwinter.AdHocHelloWorld</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>platform-identifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>AdHocHelloWorld</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```